# Solved - How to override checkout_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, overrides

I have a problem. I can't override file `checkout_index_index.xml` in my page.

I need override because this file move logo to another position in the page.

**I copied the file in the next directories: -**

```
app/design/frontend/theme/namespace/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base
app/design/frontend/theme/namespace/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/blank
app/design/frontend/theme/namespace/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/Magento/blank
```

Any one Please help

**Solved**

For override I put checkout_index_index.xml in /app/design/frontend/theme/namespace/Magento_Checkout/layout/ and put inside of file this code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="logo" destination="div.header" before="-"/>
</body>
```

Thank you All

Comment: Why do you want to override the layout, and not just extend? If you're only moving a block you should extend the layout.

Comment: Hi @Silvan , the core of magento try move element logo to another block but I need you not to move that block. Can i avoid if extend the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the checkout_index_index.xml by going to `app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout` and do a `checkout_index_index.xml` file.

In that xml file add this code which will revert the moving functionality:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header.panel"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>
```

you can change destination.

Make sure after do change, cache flush.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: That's what checkout_index_index.xml does and I want to prevent it from doing that

Comment: just put you destination="header.panel"

Comment: Ok,  But for these i need to override .xml in /vendor/magento/module_checkout/view/frontend/layout and i don't want override the core.